# Holding context, activity or views as member of a class is bad performance?

Tags: android, memory, reference, memory-leaks

I have red somewhere that keeping views as members of an activity is bad performance, because each views is keeping a reference to its parent Context and it will fill up the heap. Is this true?

**Imagine this activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{
   private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
   private LineraLayout menuLayout;
   private FrameLayout tableLayout;

   private Button buttonOk;
   private Button buttonCancel;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
      super.onCreate(bundle);

      mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
      // And inflating other views
   }
}
```

And what about **adapters**?

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   private MyActivity activity;
   private ArrayList<MyObjects> myObjects;   

   public MyAdapter (MyActivity activity, ArrayList<MyObjects> myObjects){
      this.activity = activity;
      this.myObjects = myObjects;
   }
}
```

Is this bad performance? Is it bad to pass an activity as a parameter instead of a Context? What if I want to access public methods from the parent `MyActivity` class from the adapter?

**Non-Activity class**

```
public MyDatabase{
   private Context context;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;

   public MyDatabase(Context context){
      this.context = context;
      this.db = new DatabaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public Object getData(int id){
      return db.query(params...);
   }

   public static class DatabseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
      public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
         super(context, "my_db", null, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Why people are saying that when a class constructor expects a `Context` as a parameter, you should pass `getApplicationContext()` instead of and Activity?

Answer (score 8):

To pass `Activity` instance to some method or store a reference to it somewhere is a bad practice because during configuration change Android creates a new instance of an activity and old one should be removed by garbage collector. But if someone holds a reference to an old `Activity` object it will not be collected by GC till reference to it exists. So memory leak occurs.

But in case of adapter constructor it's fully OK to pass activity instance because adapter lifecycle is coupled to activity lifecycle. Normally it will be garbage collected after activity.

`getApplicationContext` returns the context of the single, global Application object of the current process so it can be used safely throughout your application code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about bad performance, but related to possible memory leak. Pass getApplicationContext() instead of Activity is just to avoid potential memory leak.

There's nothing wrong for a activity to keep views as members, since the context of the view is activity. If activity doesn't hold the references, you need to invoke findViewById each time when you want to access the view, which will really impact the performance.About the adapter, it's still ok for you to pass activity not context.

Answer (score 0):

Passing Activity's context is what you need at the end to access the public methods of your Activity because in any which ways if you use getApplicationContext() you will have to cast it to your Activity during method calls.

```
((MainActivity)context).getMyPublicMehtods() inside the non Activity class.
```

And for more details @makovkastar has defined it very well. :)