# Using a GlobalLayoutListener in a class

Tags: java, android

Right now i'm using the code below in my main activity

```
 imageAnim.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            float x = imageAnim.getX(); // width - activity's field
            Log.d("works", "" + x); //return right value
        }
    });
```

But I want to move it to a class, but I keep getting errors like `cannot resolve symbol getViewTreeObserver`.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'd be very cautious passing view objects around that are tied to the Activity context. I would almost say just **don't do it**. If you don't clean-up the view reference passed into your `HelperClass`, you could accidentally leak memory. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644932/holding-context-activity-or-views-as-member-of-a-class-is-bad-performance) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `imageAnim` to you class as a parameter passable by the constructor

for example, create a class named `ClassHelper` as the following :

```
public class ClassHelper {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Context context;
    private float x;

    ClassHelper(ImageView imageView, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    void setViewTreeObserver() {
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                x = imageView.getX();
            }
        });
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
      }
    }
```

and call it in like this

```
   ClassHelper classHelper = new ClassHelper(imageAnim,getApplicationContext());
   classHelper.getViewTreeObserver();

   //getX() method will return the value of X
   Toast.makeText(this, "" + classHelper.getX(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: is there a way to return the value instead of using a toast? I need the value for other components

Comment: @Larrt Zeman yes, just set a getter for your X, I've updated my answer

Comment: im getting the getX() as 0

Comment: what's exactly your question? so we can help you

Comment: Basically the main problem i'm having is my imageviews x cord is coming out to 0 when i first run the activity.  The TreeObserver can get the x cord correctly, but I need to get it as a variable.  The getX there just returns 0